# Storing `find` parameters in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I'm running the following bash command:

```
find . \( -iname '*.aif' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.exe' -o -iname '*.mov' \
    -o -iname '*.doc' \) -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I'm running the same parameters in another call to `find` later on in the script. Is there any way to store the `\( -iname '*.aif' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.exe' \
        -o -iname '*.mov' -o -iname '*.doc' \)` part in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ksh, bash or zsh, use an array variable.

```
find_parameters=(\( -iname '*.aif' -o … -iname '*.doc' \))
find . "${find_parameters[@]}"
```

In other shells, there's no good way (there are complex and brittle ways but I don't recommend them unless you really need them). If you need a single array, you can use the positional parameters:

```
set \( -iname '*.aif' -o … -iname '*.doc' \)
find . "$@"
```

Comment: That works fine, thanks. So is that an array containing `\(`, `-iname`, `'*.aif'`, `-o`, `-iname`, ...? I've just never seen an array definition like that.