# find files, exclude directories

Tags: bash, command-line, find

I would like to compose a string of command line arguments in a variable, then use those to execute a command.  I show a simplified example below.  It's is a script called "listfiles."  It reads a file called "ignore" of files not to list, then is supposed to list every file except those.  What's the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
ignorelist=( `cat "./ignore" `)
for LINE in "${ignorelist[@]}"
        do
                Ignore="$Ignore -path '$LINE' -prune -o ";
        done
   
find ${Ignore} -print
```

content of ignore file (two directory names), :

```
./d1
./d2
```

output of bash -x listfiles:

```
+ ignorelist=(`cat "./ignore" `)
++ cat ./ignore
+ for LINE in '"${ignorelist[@]}"'
+ Ignore=' -path '\''./d1'\'' -prune -o '
+ for LINE in '"${ignorelist[@]}"'
+ Ignore=' -path '\''./d1'\'' -prune -o  -path '\''./d2'\'' -prune -o '
+ find -path ''\''./d1'\''' -prune -o -path ''\''./d2'\''' -prune -o -print
.
./1
./2
./3
./d1
./d1/4
./d1/d1a
./d1/d1a/5
./d2
./ignore
./listfiles
```

I would like it so that d1 and d2 and everything under is not included in the output, or so whatever files/directories are in the ignore file are not included in the output.  Would storing the whole command in a var and evaling it be better?

Comment: Related: [Storing `find` parameters in a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/storing-find-parameters-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use arrays to store things that are *separate*.  Make sure you build a valid set of options for `find`.  Don't embed extra sets of quotes in the arguments (this is ultimately what makes your command fail).

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t ignorepaths <./ignore

ignoreopts=()
for pathname in "${ignorepaths[@]}"; do
        ignoreopts+=( -o -path "$pathname" )
done

find . \( "${ignoreopts[@]:1}" \) -prune -o -print
```

See also

- [Using shell variables for command options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459367)  ...and others.

---

For `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

set --
while IFS= read -r pathname; do
    set -- "$@" -o -path "$pathname"
done <./ignore

shift

find . \( "$@" \) -prune -o -print
```

Comment: perfect!  Bash variables are a mystery to me sometimes.  I'll look at the link you posted